# Cytoscape.js selecting collapsed nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, dagre

I’ trying to build a Petri Net with Cytoscape.js, using Dagre.js layout and compound nodes for representing places witch in turns are subnets. 
I’ using Expand-Collapse extension (Dagre layout) , starting with an overall collapsed network. As the net evolve, I need to update data on every node,  including children of collapsed nodes witch users may decide to expand or not . 
Here is the issue: I’ not able to select nodes inside collapsed ones nor I can test with IsParent() or  any other function applying to compound nodes including slector like “node > node”. Any idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change state of elements that aren't in the graph.  Modify them after you add them back (`.restore()`) to the graph instead.